Convergence of $f_n(x) = \chi_{B(0,1) \setminus B(0,\frac{1}{n} )}(x) \cdot n \ln(\frac{1 + n ||x||^{\alpha}}{n ||x||^{\alpha}})$
We have $f_n: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$f_n(x) = \chi_{B(0,1) \setminus B \left( 0,\frac{1}{n} \right)} (x) \cdot n \ln \left( \frac{1 + n ||x||^{\alpha}}{n ||x||^{\alpha}} \right)$$
For which parametres $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the sequence $f_n$ is convergent in $L^1(B(0,1))$ ?
I see that the center $B(0,\frac{1}{n})$ is cut off, so we don't face any problems with denominator. As I understand, we have that:
$$f_n(x) = \chi_{B(0,1) \setminus B \left( 0,\frac{1}{n} \right)} (x) \cdot n \ln \left( \frac{1 + n ||x||^{\alpha}}{n ||x||^{\alpha}} \right)$ = \chi_{B(0,1) \setminus B \left( 0,\frac{1}{n} \right)} (x) \cdot n \ln \left( \frac{1}{n ||x||^{\alpha}} + 1 \right)$$
Because of that, we could counter the linear growth of n with $\alpha$ that would be $\in (\infty, -e)$ but I don't understand how convert that expression so to make that set more precise.
Any help would be much appreciated.
